# Accessing apostrophe-users module fields in page templates

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is there a way for me to access specific information from the apostrophe-users module in a page template?

For example, if I added a "nickname" field to apostrophe-users and would like to show a personalized welcome message on the home page to every user, is there a way to do something similar to

```
<p>Hi, {{ data.user.title }}</p>
```

in home.html but instead showing the nickname?

{{ data.user.nickname }}  currently gives me nothing. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a nickname field to `apostrophe-users` at project level you should have access to that property in your template, as you outline.

A basic implementation would look like:

In your `/lib/modules/apostrophe-users/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  addFields:[
    {
      name: 'nickname',
      label: 'Nickname',
      type: 'string'
    }
  ]
}
```

Would give you access to `{{ data.user.nickname }}`

Comment: It works! I must have messed something up yesterday. Thank you!